# Fetching a price with INNER JOIN using 3 different variables

Tags: mysql

What I have been trying to achieve is to pull a price based on 3 different variables: `brand_id`, `model_id`, `motor_id`.

The design of the tables that I am working with:

[image: My app model]

The only issue is that when I add an INNER JOIN for `databaseapp_lkp_prices` I get a zero result set (fyi, there aren't any prices currently set so `databaseapp_lkp_prices` is an empty table)

I was expecting to see `NULL` in place of the `price` for the 48,000 records that exist when I don't add the `databaseapp_lkp_prices` INNER JOIN

My query is:

```
SELECT
a.brand,
b.model,
c.motor,
d.ecu_hardware_ver,
d.ecu_software_ver,
d.ecu_software_upg_ver,
d.ecu_brand,
d.ecu_type,
d.eprom,
d.eprom_desc,
d.`checksum`,
d.checksum16,
c.motor_hp * 1.2 AS motor_hp,
e.price,
c.motor_id,
c.model_id,
c.brand_id
FROM
databaseapp_brand AS a
INNER JOIN databaseapp_model AS b ON b.brand_id = a.brand_id
INNER JOIN databaseapp_motor AS c ON b.model_id = c.model_id
INNER JOIN databaseapp_ecu AS d ON d.motor_id = c.motor_id
INNER JOIN databaseapp_lkp_prices AS e ON c.brand_id = e.brand_id AND c.model_id = e.model_id AND c.motor_id = e.motor_id
ORDER BY
a.brand ASC,
b.model ASC
```

Anyone able to help me out with why I'm getting a zero result set when I try to look up the price.

Cheers!

Comment: Inner join requires match. No match no row. You should try LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN for databaseapp_lkp_prices contribution.

Comment: Perfect, thank you - post that as the answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inner join requires match. No match no row. You should try LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN for databaseapp_lkp_prices contribution.